# gcov gets some kind of version conflict error on mac os

Tags: gcc, macos

Given a C program, call it temp.c, the following works on Linux and is supposed to work on mac os to show coverage information:

gcc -fprofile-arcs -ftest-coverage temp.c

a.out

gcov temp.c

However when I try it on my macbook pro, running mojave, gcov results in the following error

Unexpected version: *20B.
Invalid .gcno File!

my gcc version is
gcc version 10.2.0 (Homebrew GCC 10.2.0)

What has happened?

Comment: Check the output of `gcov --version`.  Is it a GCC version of `gcov` or is it LLVM/clang?  I believe he default on MacOS is `gcov` built with `clang`, have you tried compiling your software using `clang` instead of `gcc`?  You could also try to install a `gcc` based `gcov` on your Mac to see if it works better.

Comment: @GracefulRestart You were right to suspect the version of gcov in that it was the clang version, not the gcc version. Unfortunately however compiling with clang did not fix the problem; it just changed the error message to "Unexpected version: *804.
Invalid .gcno File!".  There still might be a version mismatch since the gcov version is shown as [Apple LLVM version 11.0.0 (clang-1100.0.33.17)]  whereas the clang version is  shown as 11.0.0.  I'm not sure if these are the same since gcov shows clang with a lot longer version string.